# Sinatra displaying all data to user (custom dictionary and definition app) instead of data for specific word

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Trying to make a user custom dictionary. At the index, a user is present a list of all of their custom words and have the ability to add more. They then can click a link to the specific page on a word where a user is shown their definitions and can add more.

My problem is that definitions for all words are displayed.

Below is my ruby code..

```
        class Word
      @@words = []
      define_method(:initialize) do |word|
        @word = word
        @id = @@words.length().+(1)
        @definitions = []
      end
      define_singleton_method(:all) do
        @@words
      end
      define_method(:save) do
        @@words.push(self)
      end
      define_singleton_method(:clear) do
        @@words = []
      end
      define_method(:id) do
        @id
      end
      define_singleton_method(:find) do |ident|
        found_word = nil
        @@words.each() do |word|
          if word.id.eql?(ident)
            found_word = word
          end
        end
        found_word
      end
      define_method(:add_definition) do |definition|
        @definitions.push(definition)
      end
      define_method(:definitions) do
        @definitions
      end
      define_method(:word) do
        @word
      end
    end




    class Definition
      @@definitions = []
      define_method(:initialize) do |definition, part|
        @definition = definition
        @part = part
        @id = @@definitions.length().+(1)
      end
      define_singleton_method(:all) do
        @@definitions
      end
      define_method(:save) do
        @@definitions.push(self)
      end
      define_singleton_method(:clear) do
        @@definitions = []
      end
      define_method(:id) do
        @id
      end
      define_singleton_method(:find) do |ident|
        found_definition = nil
        @@definitions.each() do |definition|
          if definition.id.eql?(ident)
            found_definition = definition
          end
        end
        found_definition
      end
      define_method(:part) do
        @part
      end
      define_method(:definition) do
        @definition
      end
    end
```

here is my sinatra page..

```
    require('sinatra')
    require('sinatra/reloader')
    also_reload('lib/**/*.rb')
    require('./lib/definition')
    require('./lib/word')

    get('/') do
      @words = Word.all()
      erb(:index)
    end

    post('/') do
      word = params.fetch('word_input')
      new_word = Word.new(word)
      new_word.save()
      @words = Word.all()
      erb(:index)
    end

    get('/word/:id') do
      @words = Word.all()
      @definitions = Definition.all
      @definition = Definition.find(params.fetch('id').to_i())
      erb(:word_page)
    end

    post('/word/:id') do
      definition = params.fetch('definition_input')
      part = params.fetch('part_input')
      new_definition = Definition.new(definition, part)
      new_definition.save
      erb(:success)
    end
```

Here is my page where I am displaying all definitions for all words

```
    <h1>Your defnitions for your word.</h1>
    <p>Here you can view your definitions for your word and add more</p>

    <% @definitions.each() do |definition| %>
    <ul>
      <li><strong>Part:</strong> <%= definition.part() %>
        <br>
        <strong>Definition:</strong> <%= definition.definition()%></li>
    </ul>

    <% end %>

    <form action="/word/:id" method="post">
      <label for="definition_input">New definition</label>
      <input id="definition_input" name="definition_input" type='text'>

      <br>

      <label for="part">New part (E.g. Verb, subj, noun)</label>
      <input id='part_input' name="part_input" type="text">
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Add defintion and the part</button>
    </form>

    <a href="/">Return to home page</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think you should clean up your code since this will make everything a lot easier for you (and in case you ask a question like this again also for the people reading your question).

See you can turn this piece of code

```
define_singleton_method(:find) do |ident|
    found_definition = nil
    @@definitions.each() do |definition|
      if definition.id.eql?(ident)
        found_definition = definition
      end
    end
    found_definition
end
```

Into this

```
def self.find(ident)
    @@definitions.each do |definition|
        if definition.id == ident
            return definition
        end
    end
    nil
end
```

Not really beautiful either, you could transform it into something like this:

```
def self.find(ident)
    @@definitions.find{|definition| definition.id == ident}
end
```

Now this doesn't answer your question though, but I think coding style is important, so I wanted to point this out nevertheless.

The problem you have is that inside of your view you are calling

`@definitions.each() do |definition|`

You reference `@definitions` which is filled by the call in your sinatra server, you need to reference `@definition` and embed this into your view since you don't want to display all definitions. (You might want to create a second view for this).